# I have the Balls set and want to increase the score when the ball enters the hole ,but the scores continues to increase even after the ball is removed

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-physics, 2d-games

function for the goals named `startScoring`

```
if theBall.position.x <= theHole.position.x && theBall.position.y <= TheHole.position.y {
            addScore(Player: Player!)
            HideTheBall(theBallInTheHole: theBall)
            theBall.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
            theBall.physicsBody?.angularVelocity = 0
        }
```

---

```
func addScore(Player: String){
    Ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    if random == 0 {
        score[0] += 10
    }else {
        score[1] += 10
    } 
    topLbl.text = "\(score[1])"
    btmLbl.text = "\(score[0])"
}
func HideTheBall(theBallInTheHole: SKSpriteNode) {
    theBallInTheHole.removeFromParent()
}
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
   StartScoring()
}
```

Comment: what is theBall theHole? can you show more code on how you are creating theBall/theHole etc?

Comment: look to the answer pls

Comment: From where you call this function?

Comment: override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        
        // Called before each frame is rendered
       StartScoring()
    }

Comment: when you call `BallinTheHole(theBall: someBall, theHole: someHole` method, how did you get `theBall` and `theHole` sprites? Are they class members? do you create new before calling `BallinTheHole`?

Comment: ya , it working great actually, but I did not keep all the code because it is a bit long, but my problem is centered around the score because it continues to grow and does not stop even when I remove the balls.

Comment: the idea of the game is to add score when the ball in the hole ,

Comment: As i don't the code for proper fix. I can suggest you a simple solution. Create a class variable `var isGameOver = false`. `In HideTheBall` you can set `isGameOver = true` and in `addScore`, you can just return if `isGameOver` is true as. `guard isGameOver == false else { return }`

Comment: think you so much I will try it , sorry I take from time

Comment: Just because a ball is removed from parent, does not mean that ball gets deleted.  You are keeping that ball in memory, so when you are running your checks on your update function, it is going to use the same spot the ball was in before it was removed from parent